# Access ViewModel fields in Edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

My Model:

```
public ECmain()
{
    this.Notes = new Collection<Notes>();
}

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Auth { get; set; }
    public string KeyWords { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Live { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Email { get; set; }
}
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<Notes> NotesList { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<ECmain> ECmainList { get; set; }
    public int ECmain.ID { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Email> EmailList { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
// GET: ECmain/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel
    {
        ECmainList = from m in db.ECmain.Take(10)
                     where m.ID ==  id
                     select m,
        NotesList = from n in db.Notes
                    where n.ECmainID ==id
                    select n,
        EmailList = from e in db.Email
                    where e.ECmainID ==id
                    select e
    };
    // viewModel.NotesList = new 

    if (viewModel == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

My Edit View:

```
@model EditSuite.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID )
```

I want to access the ECmainList.ID The error is

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'EditSuite.Models.MyViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ID'

I tried

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ECmainListID.ID )
```

and

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Model.model.ECmainListID.ID )
```

Neither one worked.

Comment: After your update, your model makes absolutely no sense.  You have a constructor that belongs to nothing, and a bunch of properties that also belong to nothing.

Comment: Make a public property ID in your ViewModel and simply assign a copy of the ID you have used to query data. Then you will be able to refer to it in your View

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty obvious from the compiler message:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'EditSuite.Models.MyViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ID'

So where on the following model is the ID?:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public IQueryable<Notes> NotesList { get; set; }
  public IQueryable<ECmain> ECmainList { get; set; }
  public IQueryable<Email> EmailList { get; set; }
  // there is no: public int ID { get; set; } ?
}
```

> I want to access the ECmainList.ID

However, per your model the `ECmainList` is a `IQueryable<ECmain>` and the `IQueryable<T>` also does not have a public property or field called `ID`.  How can you add an editor for a ID of a list of objects?  You'd need to loop through the list and have multiple ID fields.

Comment: Please check my edit. I added public int ID { get; set; } in ECmain

Comment: This is my first attempt at MVC and I am trying to learn. I am trying to work with 3 related tables with a one to many relationship. ECmain Notes and Email. Ultimately I want to simplify CRUD to one screen. Obviously I lost my path somewhere. Can you point me in a direction?

Comment: First update your first code example, it doesn't make sense.  If you are trying to edit a single ECMain, then you need to pull back just the one record and not an IQuerable one.

Comment: I also learn MVC and it takes significant time. I can recommend these tutorials I found useful: [ASP.NET MVC for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v), or if you also need to learn C# [C# for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAC325451207E3105)